Weird whitish tint over video feed from the canvas frame

I have a JFrame, on that a JPanel, on that a JButton.
Of JButton, I have handled JButton.actionPerformed() event of it.
But when I click on the JButton to open the canvasFrame where the image be shown, there is a
whitish tint over that.
Also please tell how to flip the image as on webcam it is mirrored.
P.S. I have installed OpenCV to access the camera and JavaCV as wrapper.
Can it be due to the reason that I have installed old jar files of JavaCV and are not compatible
with newer machines?

I tried this:-
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Thread webcam;
    webcam = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            CvCapture capture = opencv_highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
            opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture,opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);
            opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture,opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,720);

            IplImage grabbedImage = opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture);
            CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Webcam");
            frame.setSize(720,720);
            while(frame.isVisible())
            {
                grabbedImage=opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture);
                if(grabbedImage==null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
                IplImage rgbImage = IplImage.create(grabbedImage.width(), grabbedImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
        opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(grabbedImage, rgbImage, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2RGB);
        
            }
            opencv_highgui.cvReleaseCapture(capture);
            grabbedImage.release();
           
        }
    };
    webcam.start();
}

And was expecting the whitish tint to be removed. But the whitish tint is still there.

can you show us what you mean?
